# htaccess rule to handle non-exist website page request from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

Currently, I have written the rule below so any non-exist website page request goes to default page of website.

```
RewriteEngine on  
ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}
```

For Example: `www.example.com/non-exist-page-name` request goes to this page `www.example.com`.

But this is not working when any non-exist page request comes from subdomain.

For Example: `sub.example.com/non-exist-page-name` request gives **Page Not Found** error.

So what rule I need to write in `.htaccess` so when any non-exist page request comes from subdomain, it goes to website default page like `www.sitename.com` OR is there any other way to handle this from hosting server side?

Comment: Is your subdomain processing the same `.htaccess` file? What is the file structure? Where do the main domain and subdomain point to? (Redirecting all 404's to the homepage is generally a bad idea....?)

Comment: @MrWhite, actually no subdomain is created right now. Site is under construction right now. But if user access website using any non-exist website page, it goes to default page but if user access website using any non-exist subdomain page then it is giving error. Please let me know if you need more clarification. Ty

Comment: "no subdomain is created right now" - what "error" are you getting exactly? If a subdomain doesn't exist then the request won't even resolve!?